# Calling function defined on $scope from another function defined on $scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller with many functions defined on `$scope`.

Ex:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {

}

$scope.doSomethingElse = function(data) {

}
```

From my `doSomething` function, I want to call my `doSomethingElse` function.  Right now, I am calling it in the success function of my HTTP request (yes, it is succeeding).

Once the success function triggers, I'm calling the other function like so:

`angular.scope().doSomethingElse(data);`  The `data` variable is passed through as a parameter in the success function.

After running, I'm receiving this error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What does angular.scope() return? My first hunch is that this returns undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call `$scope.doSomethingElse(data);` since you've already defined it as a function.  As long as it is defined before you call it, this will work.

Comment: I had already tried that -- still getting `undefined is not a function`

Comment: @NoahMatisoff  Try moving your definition of `$scope.doSomethingElse` before you call it.